# linux console on nuc without serial ports

Tags: linux, console

I'm running a small, headless home nas + dvr on an intel nuc using ubuntu server, nothing particularly grand. I have occasionally run into problems if I have to reboot it for one reason or another and it fails to restart (gets stuck somewhere during boot or shutdown maybe) When this happens it can be a pain to figure out what's going on since I often can't ssh in and there's no monitor/keyboard where it's set up etc.

I know of the existence of the serial console, but I haven't really been able to find solid info on how I would set this up with the devices I have. The nuc has no serial port or ethernet, nor do I have any other machine with a serial port I can use.

What alternative could I use to obtain serial console from the nuc on a laptop? Is something like a usb->serial->serial->usb setup between 2 devices possible? Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You need a usb bridge cable. A normal cable could litterally burn your computer(s). And you need to enable network over usb on both. But i can't say, if that will solve your problem.!

Comment: Thanks, that's a start, I'll look into those. Definitely don't want to fry anything!